# How to to gather applicative logs from an Azure VM and send them to Elasticstack running on my host's VM using VMware?

Tags: azure, api, logging, elastic-stack, elk

I'm currently working on a project that involves collecting applicative logs from a Saas application hosted on Azure Microsoft. The goal is to gather these logs into my Elasticstack SIEM, which is installed on a virtual machine (VM) on-prem. This setup will enable me to develop detection rules based on the Saas application logs, specifically for purposes like fraud detection or identifying account takeover attempts.

To make a PoC, I have decided to install Juiceshop on an Azure VM. Juiceshop is available for download at [juiceshop](https://github.com/juice-shop/juice-shop). My aim is to collect the application logs from Juiceshop web app, but I have encountered some difficulties, and I'm unsure about the feasibility and the necessary steps to achieve this.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in this matter, or even better ideas to achieve this, thank you!

I have installed ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) on an Ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS virtual machine. Additionally, I have set up system integration to collect system logs and establish a foothold. However, the main objective is to gather **application** logs from a Saas application.